# Spring MVC 3: <mvc:annotation-driven/> in eclipse

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.0.5 in Eclipse 3.5 but in my servlet context I am getting a warning against `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`.

The warning says:

```
Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for element 'mvc:annotation-driven' of schema namespace 'http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/mvc' in eclipse.
```

The namespace declaration of my servlet context is:
**myapp-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd      
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

...
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

Could somebody help me understand why am I getting that warning in Eclipse 3.5?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning your Eclipse's cache: `Preferences > General > Network Connections > Cache.` Hopefully this works out.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me. And I am struggling with this problem a a couple of days... I mean, a dozen couple of days!